# Input/Output error Ubuntu crashes with grey icons

Tags: ssd, freeze

Good morning,

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on my Asus Vivobook S14 hard drive. Everything goes well but each time (I tried many times, dual booting then deleting Windows and emptying the disk), after a while Ubuntu crashes, the icons turn gray and I have errors of input/output. I can't do anything anymore, I have to completely shutdown my laptot.

Edit:
I tried to install Ubuntu 22.10 Desktop but also Ubuntu Mate and Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop and it is the same problem.
It is always an IO error no m’atterrît which action i am doing when it crashes.
I’ve tried for 6 months i dont understand. I was able to install it on an usb drive but not on my ssd.

Someone can help me ???

Thanks in advance

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because  it is not in English. Please [edit] your question and translate it to English using any appropriate online translation facility.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to this website. I now have edited my questions for you guys to be able to understand it. Thanks for your quick answer !

Comment: Ubuntu product/release details are helpful, eg. Ubuntu has *five* different installers available, which you select by the ISO you download and install; we don't know what Ubuntu product, thus what choices you have available let alone used. Please add Ubuntu product details; eg. Ubuntu Server? Ubuntu Desktop? Ubuntu Core?  what release of that product etc, eg. Ubuntu Server 22.10 for example...   The exact IO error is also helpful; eg. if trying to install the device should be viewable that tells you if the IO relates to installation media OR to where you're installing; but you didn't paste...

Comment: I am really new to this world si it is difficult for me to understant exactly what you want but I know it is Ubuntu 22.10 but I tried with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and Ubuntu Mate and the same problem happenened. Also when the error happens I 've seen a lot of 'read only file systeme' errors I don't know if there is a link ?

Comment: If you can take a picture of the error message & provide a link to it that would be helpful (*don't worry if it's not in English; I'm a dumb aussie & can barely speak english let alone other languages... but the picture will still provide clues I can use & others on this site maybe able to read the non-english too! It's the question text we need in english*).  The Ubuntu 22.10 & Ubuntu-MATE 22.04 detail belongs in the question (ie. Ubuntu-MATE is a desktop system so you likely also mean Ubuntu 22.10 Desktop..)

Comment: Ok i will try to do this but It can take some time because i dont now when the next error will happen. Yes I think uou are right it's Ubuntu 22.10 desktop

Comment: So I was able to take a picture (low quality sorry but i can't to better with my device). The error happened and THEN I tried to lauch spotify so the error says in English :" Impossible to lauch Spotify. The execution of the child process /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/gio-launch-desktop has failed (IO error)". I dont know how to send my picture that I took but it shows the error in French and the icons of my apps becoming grey rectangle

Comment: Please [edit] your question and consolidate all the information you provided in your comments *into your question text*.